# string literal is not properly closed by a double-quote

Tags: android, sql, database, string

Hey everyone ;)
I have the following code:

```
private void onCreateDBAndDBTables(){
 myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Projects", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
 myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + MY_DB_TABLE 
   + "( _id integer primary key autoincrement
     name varchar (16),
     comment varchar (128),
     customer_project boolean,
     booking_details varchar (225),
     editable boolean )"  
       +";");
}
```

and it shows the error as mentioned in the Title.
I hope you can help me out here, because I have no idea what's wrong...
~sam~

Comment: Shouldn't `autoincrement` be `auto_increment`?

Comment: You don't even need to put autoincrement in for SQLite3 actually. You can just leave it out, and when inserting data, put in NULL for the key and it will automatically auto increment. Also updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 4):

Every new line in the string you need to concatenate:

```
private void onCreateDBAndDBTables(){
 myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Projects", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
 myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + MY_DB_TABLE +
              "( _id integer primary key," +
              "name varchar (16)," +
              "comment varchar (128)," +
              "customer_project boolean," +
              "booking_details varchar (225)," +
              "editable boolean )" +  
              ";");
}
```

*** Update ***

I also noticed that you were using SQLite3, so I updated the SQL a bit - removed the `autoincrement`.

Check out this article on how auto increment works in SQLite3:

http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing a comma after autoincrement (it should be auto_increment). And there is no type boolean in SQL. Have you considered using the [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) class? An example is included in the [Notepad Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a comma after `autoincrement` and then you don't need the trailing semicolon

Comment: The error is with the string itself, not the SQL query, but good catch.

Answer (score 0):

this is my full code! :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

import datenbank.test.R.id;
import android.R.layout;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AbsSpinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Projects_new extends Activity {

```
SQLiteDatabase myDB = null;
  static final int MENU_INSERT_PROJECTS = 0;
  static final int MENU_UPDATE_PROJECTS = 0;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.activity_list_item);

    Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.PROJECTS_NEW);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, 
            (MENU_INSERT_PROJECTS),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s1.setAdapter(adapter);

    if(getIntent().hasExtra("id") == true) {
        long l = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("id");
        myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(datenbank.MY_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        Cursor myCursor = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT name,comment, customer_project, booking_details, editable FROM" + 
                datenbank.MY_DB_TABLE + "WHERE _id = "+l+";", null);

        startManagingCursor(myCursor);

        int ColumnName = myCursor.getColumnIndex("name"); //Name
        int ColumnComment = myCursor.getColumnIndex("Comment"); //Comment
        int ColumnCustomer_Project = myCursor.getColumnIndex ("Customer-Project?");//ist es für customer oder intern
        int ColumnBooking_Details = myCursor.getColumnIndex("Details"); //details
        int ColumnEditable = myCursor.getColumnIndex("Editable?"); //bearbeiten ja oder nein

         if (myCursor != null) {
                if (myCursor != null) { 
                    EditText eName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.PROJECTS_NEW);
                    eName.setText(myCursor.getString(ColumnName));

                    EditText eComment = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.PROJECTS_NEW);
                    eComment.setText(myCursor.getString(ColumnComment));

                    EditText eCustomer_Project = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.PROJECTS_NEW);
                    eCustomer_Project.setText(myCursor.getString(ColumnCustomer_Project));


                    Spinner sBooking_Details = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.PROJECTS_NEW);
                    sBooking_Details.setSelection(myCursor.getInt(ColumnBooking_Details), true);

                    EditText eEditable = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.PROJECTS_NEW);
                    eEditable.setText(myCursor.getString(ColumnEditable));
                }
  }}
}

  private void setContentView(Class<layout> class1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private EditText findViewById(id id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

      if(getIntent().hasExtra("id")==true)
      {
          menu.add(0, MENU_UPDATE_PROJECTS, 0, R.string.MENU_PROJECTS)
          .setShortcut('1','s')
          .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_save);

      }
      else
      {
          menu.add(0, MENU_INSERT_PROJECTS, 0, R.string.MENU_PROJECTS)
          .setShortcut('1','s')
          .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_save);
      }
      return true;

  }

  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case MENU_INSERT_PROJECTS:
            EditText Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_Name);
            EditText Comment = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_Comment);
            EditText CustomerProject = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_CustomerProject);
            EditText BookingDetails = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_BookingDetails);
            Spinner Editable = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.cb_Editable);

            int i = Editable.getSelectedItemPosition();

            if(Name.length()!=0){
                myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(datenbank.MY_DB_NAME,
                        MODE_PRIVATE, null);


            }

            //Projekt-Daten updaten (UPDATE)        
            if(getIntent().hasExtra("id") == true)
            {
                long l = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("id");
                myDB.execSQL("UPDATE "+datenbank.MY_DB_TABLE+" SET "+
                        "name = '"+Name.getText().toString()+"', "+
                    "Comment = '"+Comment.getText().toString()+"', "+
                    "BookingDetails ='"+BookingDetails.getText().toString()+"', "+
                    "Editable ='"+i+"', "+
                    "CustomerProject = '"+CustomerProject.getText().toString()+"' "+
                    "WHERE _id = "+l+";"); 
            }

            //Neues Projekt in Datenbank speichern (INSERT)             
            else
            {                   
                myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO" +datenbank.MY_DB_TABLE +"
                                                                  (Name,  
                                                                  Comment,
                                                                  BookingDetails,
                                                                  Editable,  
                                                                  CustomerProject) 
                        +"VALUES ('"+Name.getText().toString()+"',"+
                        "'"+Comment.getText().toString()+"',"+
                        "'"+BookingDetails.getText().toString()+"',"+
                        "'"+i+"',"+"'"+CustomerProject.getText().toString()+"');");
            }
            finish();
            return true;    
        }
        else
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a name for the new Project!", 
                                                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

    return false;
}
```

}